# Start process WMI maximized on another computer

Tags: c#

I have created a program to start a process on another computer. It does the job but if I want to show the process (ie notepad.exe) maximized I don't know how to achive it...

This is my code

```
    private void btnStartNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] arrParams = {txtNewProcess.Text.Trim()};
        
        try
        {
            manageClass = new ManagementClass(myScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
            manageClass.InvokeMethod("Create", arrParams);
        

            btnConnect_Click(sender, e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need to add two additional args, 1st working directory, 2nd an instance of "Win32_ProcessStartup" with ShowWindow property set to 3.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-process

Comment: Thanks for your answer but reagrding to your link, it's not possible. For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely. That means that the process is started but not shown in the screen...